# Makefile for SDL application only runs when the project has been built ahead of time

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

Alright, so this one is absolutely blowing my mind. Basically, I've got a simple makefile set up that runs g++ to build my bare-bones C++ project with SDL2. Now, when I run this makefile, it gives me a bunch of errors for "undefined reverence to 'SDL_Init'" and every function taken from SDL2 that I use in the program. However, when I copy the command from the makefile and run it from the terminal, everything is peachy. Without changing the file and running  the make file again, it compiles just fine.

I am running Elementary OS Loki, g++ version 5.4.0 20160609, make version 4.1, libsdl2-dev version 2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2

Here is the make file that I am using:

Makefile

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -g -Wall
LFLAGS = -lSDL2

ONAME = patchworkrpg

all: $(ONAME)
    $(CC) $(ONAME).cpp $(LFLAGS) -o $(ONAME)
```

patchworkrpg.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL Failed to init\n";
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I've striped out some of the extra stuff I had in there, but that's the gist of it. Like I said, the only thing that throws errors is the makefile when it's run, without the above file being compiled outside of the makefile with an identical command.

EDIT: Extra info

Errors when running the makefile:

```
g++     patchworkrpg.cpp   -o patchworkrpg
/tmp/cctyEbxS.o: In function `main':
patchworkrpg.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
patchworkrpg.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
patchworkrpg.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
patchworkrpg.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'patchworkrpg' failed
make: *** [patchworkrpg] Error 1
```

Command typed into the terminal that works just fine:

```
g++ patchworkrpg.cpp -lSDL2 -o patchworkrpg
```

I've also tried running that exact command from the makefile and it's failed with the exact same errors

Comment: Could you at least add *full* output of your compilation? Should't be too long since there is only one SDL function call. Without it, it is more like a guesswork.

Comment: Also the command you type on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Your example Makefile and source file were incomplete, so I had to edit them to test this.)

In your Makefile:

```
ONAME = patchworkrpg

all: $(ONAME)
    $(CC) $(ONAME).cpp $(LFLAGS) -o $(ONAME)
```

`all` depends on `patchworkrpg`, but there is no rule to make `patchworkrpg`, so make creates the  implicit rule  `g++     patchworkrpg.cpp   -o patchworkrpg` you see on the fly.

Not quite sure how you try to organize things, but to actually run your own command line this change should fix it:

`all: $(ONAME).cpp`